# How to call a python function within quotation marks

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a function that generates some part of a string, and is going to be called within another string, so that it completes the sentence.

The restriction, however, is that this complete string must be set in quotation marks. It looks something like:

`date = 'The date is get_date()'`

where get_date() is a function that returns the date in a string (though is a little more complicated than that). The problem is that python wont let me call a function within quotation marks.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:
I'll be more specific about what I'm trying to do, since I don't think it's that complicated, and you seem like a helpful bunch.

I've got a configuration file (conf.py) that is defining a bunch of variables. One of them that I'd like to manipulate (using a python script) is copyright year:

`one_of_the_options = [('example1', 'Copyright 2008-CURRENTYEAR Company Name Ltd.')]`

CURRENTYEAR is what I'd like to control via the output of a python script, where my function just returns the year as a string.

Comment: Are you fixed that you're looking for what looks like a function call in the string, or are Pythonic and less-horrendous alternatives acceptable? If so, we'd need more information on how you intend to use this...

Comment: May be you need string formatting: `'The date is {}'.format(get_date())`

Comment: To expand on what @Jon asked: where are you getting this string? Do you have any control over it? Does the "function call" absolutely have to look like a function call in the string, or can you do something less horrible, like provide a normal [format string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just `format` or append the result of the function in to the string?  It looks like you may be coming from the world of shell scripting.  In programming languages, string literals are generally not evaluated; rather, if you need to use a result of a function call in them, you manipulate the data outside of the string literal expression.  Can you give more context for your use case?

Comment: I see you've sussed me out. I was doing this before using shell scripts but it was getting ugly. I've updated the question to say more explicitly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @user1488804 I thought your original question was pretty clear... you were clearly coming from a Bash or Perl background and wanted to call the function in the quotes like you would in one of those languages.  Just saying that not all readers felt you needed to be sussed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
date = 'The date is {}'.format(get_date())
```

The above uses a formatted string, much simpler (and safer) than evaluating code in a string - and the actual function to be evaluated could be passed as a parameter, for increased flexibility. For instance, for the example after the edit:

```
def get_current_year():
    return '2013' # just an example, not the real function

s = 'Copyright 2008-{} Company Name Ltd.'
s.format(get_current_year())
=> 'Copyright 2008-2013 Company Name Ltd.'
```

Formatted strings allow you to substitute the `{}` placeholder within a string with any value you want, in particular, it can be a function call. Read more about format strings in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).

Answer (score 2):

Oscar's solution will definitely work, but there's another option out there that might work depending on your use case. For instance, if you are using a function from some module but you're not sure which function and you get it as a string, you can cast that string back to the function in question in a way that is non-ideal, but not nearly as bad as `eval`. For instance:

```
import requests

def run_request(method, **kwargs):
    return getattr(requests, method)(**kwargs)
```

Since functions are objects in python you can in fact retrieve them via string representation. I would still agree that you don't want to if you can avoid it.

In response to your update there's an alternate syntax that you might like, but it's pretty much just a simple alternative to Oscar's answer. Say you have a function `year` that returns what you want. You can do this:

```
"Copyright 2008-%s" % your_function()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your conf file is already a python script, then you can just run python code directly in it.  To blatantly crib @Óscar López's answer:

```
one_of_the_options = [('option1', 'Copyright 2008-{} Company Name Ltd.'.format(current_year()))]
```

Comment: Appreciated. I've given @Óscar López's the credit for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me a perfect opportunity to use templates.

So you'd write something like this:

```
one_of_the_options = [('example1', 'Copyright 2008-{{ curent_year }} Company Name Ltd.')]
```

And then instead of outputting the text directly, you render it using a template engine first.

The [Templating](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating) page on the Python Wiki has a good overview of using templates.

Answer (score 1):

Or could you just use string concatenation:

> date = 'The date is ' + str(get_date())